# I quit my job and now I want it back

Tags: ethics, employer-relations, unprofessional-behavior, job-description, pakistan

I quit my job in March 2018, because my boss made me angry by accusing me of stealing some important documents. In anger, I quit my job. I tried my best to get another job, but I fail to do so.

Now I want my old job back, but my boss is very rude and strict person. I had tried my best to assure my boss that I didn't steal his documents, but he didn't not believe me.

What can I do to get my old job back?

Comment: Your best bet is to probably find another job at this point. It's been 4 months. Did you ever find one?

Answer (score 23):

You have learned that doing things in anger is very rarely a good idea. In the future, when you are angry, do nothing, wait until you have calmed down, then think about what you want to achieve and how you can achieve it, and act accordingly.

That said, it is eight months since you left. For the company, you don't exist anymore. Your position will be long filled. After a week, your boss might have been happy for you to come back, after eight months you are just one of possibly many people wanting a job at this company.

In addition, your ex-boss still believes that you have been stealing documents. In this situation, your chances to get your old job back are very, very slim. You can apply if there is an open position, and maybe you are accepted, but the chances are very low.